# Not getting Access Token for Facebook authorization in an android app even after calling openActiveSession()?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-oauth

I have created a Button in the UI which on clicking should call a function(fbLogin()), which opens a Session (if closed) and authorizes the user.

```
public void fbLogin(View button) {
    Log.e(getClass().getName(), "0");
    Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session == null) {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "1");
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "2");
            session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback,
                    savedInstanceState);
        }
        if (session == null) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "3");
            session = new Session(this);
        }
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "4");
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "5");
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
                    .setCallback(statusCallback));
        }
    }
    Log.e(getClass().getName(), "6");
    updateView();
}
```

updateView():

```
private void updateView() {
    final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session.isOpened()) {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "7");

        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    // callback after Graph API response with user object
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                            Response response) {
                        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "8");
                        if (user != null) {
                            String str = user.getName();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    getApplicationContext(), LoggedIn.class);
                            Log.e(getClass().getName(), user.getName());
                            intent.putExtra("UserName", str);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                });

    }

    else {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "9");
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
                    if(session.isOpened()) Log.e(getClass().getName(), "15");
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "AT : "+ session.getAccessToken());
        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    // callback after Graph API response with user object
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                            Response response) {
                        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "10");

                        if(user==null) Log.e(getClass().getName(), "11");
                        if (user != null) {
                            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "12");
                            String str = user.getName();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    getApplicationContext(), LoggedIn.class);
                            Log.e(getClass().getName(), user.getName());
                            intent.putExtra("UserName", str);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                });

    }

}
```

My SessionStatusCallback class:

```
private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "13");

        // updateView();
    }
}
```

But when I do click the Login Button the activity keeps on Loading (as if it is fetching a token),but the session never opens(as the logger never logs 15 in LogCat)

LogCat Output :

```
08-12 16:11:35.836: E/com.example.usemeone.UsemeOne(1725): 0
08-12 16:11:35.846: E/com.example.usemeone.UsemeOne(1725): 1
08-12 16:11:35.846: E/com.example.usemeone.UsemeOne(1725): 3
08-12 16:11:35.886: E/com.example.usemeone.UsemeOne(1725): 4
08-12 16:11:35.896: E/com.example.usemeone.UsemeOne(1725): 6
08-12 16:11:35.896: E/com.example.usemeone.UsemeOne(1725): 9
08-12 16:11:36.046: E/com.example.usemeone.UsemeOne(1725): AT : 
08-12 16:11:36.366: E/com.example.usemeone.UsemeOne$SessionStatusCallback(1725): 13
08-12 16:11:37.196: E/com.example.usemeone.UsemeOne$2(1725): 10
08-12 16:11:37.196: E/com.example.usemeone.UsemeOne$2(1725): 11
```

Comment: Did you use a sample Android-facebook app to begin with?

Comment: See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/ or https://github.com/fbsamples

Comment: Well I made using the samples itself(SessionLoginSample) with slight modifications and all the prerequisites are done from Facebook developers page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you implementing `onActivityResult()` for the `Session`? It won't finish the authentication otherwise.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == Session.DEFAULT_AUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY_CODE) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (Session.getActiveSession() != null)
            Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
                    resultCode, data);

        Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (currentSession == null || currentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
            Session session = new Session.Builder(this).build();
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            currentSession = session;
        }

        if (currentSession.isOpened()) {
            Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, no change. Same result in LogCat. Anyway how would this change the result as onActivityResult will be called only if I exit that activity but I am never exiting that activity.

Comment: Ah, I changed my app name in Eclipse and never modified it in Facebook App registration.